# nodejs get mac address of client

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, mac-address

I created a Tcp server using **net** module in NodeJS and tried to get the mac address info from each client to generate uuid. However, in the Socket object, there is no information about it. Also I tried to get read mac address from arp table, but it's not working either. Any other ways to figure it out?

Comment: That makes no sense at all in a production environment. You won't see the actual MAC address of the client, but you'll get, if any, at maximum the MAC address of the router nearest to your server (in most cases: the server's default gateway). This is how the internet works. So you would generate the same UUID for all random visitors that come from outside the local network

Comment: I see, Thank you, @Psi

Answer (score 11):

Because the MAC address belongs to the layer 2 of the OSI layers you will not be able to access it unless you are in the same address space because it gets stripped out by routers.

**Explanation**

MAC address, belongs to layer 2 "Data Link Layer" of [7 OSI Layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). The clients' MAC addresses are only visible to the routers they directly connect to.

Routers will partially disassemble the packet to get at the layer 3 "Network Layer" headers in order to determine where the packet should be shipped, where IP address is being used.

Then, Layer 4, "Transport Layer", is where you're talking about specific protocols, like TCP.

Therefore, as a server, you **CANNOT** get the clients' MAC address unless you are connected to your clients in layer 2.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. This is just an explanation, in which cases there is no solution

Comment: @Psi Which is perfectly acceptable. This is valuable information. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar before for class rooms in production environment. In my case, I have access to all client machines. Either you have admin access to all clients or you can pre-register the client into your database somehow, you can do the following. If not, please ignore this answer.

1. Create another NodeJs program hosted a web service in Clients (Don't forget to implement some kind of security). This program could be just a simple ExpressJs with getmac node module.
2. Register all IPs or domain name of the clients to Server database. Could be manual or, in my case, when Client turned-on it's auto send a request to server to register itself. (Implement client-server validation if needed)
3. When Server needed the mac from client, Server app sends a request to each pre-registered client to get its mac address or any other information Server needs from clients.

Answer (score 0):

Net client in node js does not provide the mac address. You have the choice between :

1- sending the @mac your self: i mean in the client side you send the Mac address as data  when you establish connection with the server.

2- use socket.io insteed  net . It will afford you all the information you want

Comment: In my eyes, your solution #1 is the only possibility. Unless the system is only intended for an intranet-usage, retrieving the MAC-address will not work that way.